# Will the chat feature in mobile apps be updated or usable in 2019 and later?

Tags: bug, ios-app

I have tried using an android phone (Samsung S7) & an iPad pro with the same result. No automatic login.
If ithere is a mandatory requirement that one must be logged into a computer such as a laptop or desktop shouldn't that be public knowledge such as a pop up when one tries to enter a chat?

Comment: Do you log out? I don't log out of the app or chat and my session persists pretty much indefinitely. Can you explain what you're doing?

Comment: The iOS app does not have native chat support. If you're clicking the chat link inside the app, it's actually opening a link into your browser. So if you're not logged in with your browser, it will not auto-login for you. You'll have to do so, at which point it should be remembered for future sessions, so long as your mobile browser isn't set to forget about it when it closes.

Comment: Also, development on the apps is no longer taking place I think. The mobile site, and/or the responsive site are your friends when using a small screen.